# My React app looks great when run locally. When run in production, some content shifts to the left

Tags: reactjs

Like the title says, my app looks great when running on localhost, but in production some content shifts to the left.  My build folder is up to date.  Any ideas what's causing this?

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import githubLogo from "../../assets/contact-images/github-logo-175x175.jpg";

const styles = {
  navbar: {
    color: "white",
    // backgroundColor: "rgb(30, 8, 153)",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
    fontSize: "24px",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
};

function Contact() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} md={4}>
          <a
            href="https://github.com/Xr7TSi"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={styles.navbar}
            target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <Image src={githubLogo} rounded />
            <h5>GitHub</h5>
          </a>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: We will need to see something here: code, or images, or something.  Try to come up with a minimal reproducible example and people will be able to help.

Comment: could be a caching issue in the browser. could be a browser thing like for example some things display different in firefox than chrome or edge

Comment: I just downloaded firefox.  It renders there the same as in chrome.

Comment: Also added some code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the problem by removing "justify content: "center""(which seemed to have no effect whether it was there or not) and adding "marginLeft: "30px"" to const styles.

Now, when I run my app directly from the code in localhost, items are shifted to the right as you'd exprect.  However, when serving the build folder, it looks great.

I'm not crazy about this workaround and still don't understand why my build folder renders differently than the code outside my build folder.  But, my deployed app looks good.

```
const styles = {
  navbar: {
    color: "white",
    // backgroundColor: "rgb(30, 8, 153)",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
    fontSize: "24px",
    marginLeft: "30px",
  },
};
```